# Submit the form returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit the form returned by ajax but it's not submitting the form.

Here is the code I tried

This file is called 3.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#submitform").on("click", function(){
       $.post("4.php").done(function(data){
         //$($.parseHTML(data)).find("#paypalsubmit").submit();
         $($.parseHTML(data)).find("input[type='submit']").submit();
       });
      });

    });
    </script>
    <div id="submitform">click</div>
```

4.php file

```
    <form id="paypalsubmit" method="post" action="stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="text" value="hello stack" name="inputt">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

**update** used click function and it worked

Tried another method still it doesn't work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#submitform").on("click", function(){
        alert("hello");
       $.post("4.php").done(function(data){
        $("#formplace").html(data).find("#paypalsubmit").submit();
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("submitting the form");
            //$("#formplace").find("#paypalsubmit").submit();},
            //$("#paypalsubmit").submit();},
            $("#formplace").find("input[type='submit']").click();},
            2000);


       });

      });

    });
    </script>
    <div id="submitform">click</div>

    <div id="formplace"> </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this form being added dynamically after an event with AJAX. In other words it doesn't exist before hand?

Comment: So you make an AJAX request to get a `<form>` element and then you immediately what to submit that form via AJAX too? This is really weird behaviour. Whats the reason you need to do it this way?

Comment: @DCdaz I am retrieving the form as a ajax response. form comes only after ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks ,you can't submit without action ("click") for new appended one ! For me ,used trigger is working .Find type submit instead of form id

```
 $(function(){
      $("#submitform").on("click", function(){
        alert("hello");
       $.post("4.php").done(function(data){
        $("#formplace").html(data).find(":submit").trigger("click");
      });    
    });
```

Comment: Yes tried by myself it's working thanks for your answer and your time

Answer (score 2):

Instead use a virtual div to hold the form and then ***submit the form*** instead:

```
$.post("4.php").done(function(data){
   var $div = $('<div>',{ html : data });
   $div.find("form")[0].submit();
});
```

Not sure if form can be submitted as above i suggested. But another way is to put the form in the page and then submit it:

```
$.post("4.php").done(function(data){
   $('body').append(data);
   $("#paypalsubmit")[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: got this error Uncaught TypeError: $div.find(...)[0].submit is not a function in console

Comment: @scriptkiddie can you confirm that you get the form in the done callback?

Comment: yes I am getting the form from ajax call only form exist in 4.php not in 3.php

Comment: @scriptkiddie `console.log(data)` does this logs the form?

Comment: I have used alert(data). It alerted the data

Comment: @scriptkiddie then do one thing put the form in the page somewhere and then submit the form.

Comment: please see my update I tried but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line

```
$($.parseHTML(data)).find("input[type='submit']").submit();
```

To

```
$("#paypalsubmit").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change out your on click for

```
$("#submitform").on("click", "#submitform", function() {
```

This will allow jQuery to see the newly created submit button.